# jQuery areas elements only added once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working on a little game for practicing jquery.

The script I made add area's to a html map element.
But it only adds an area once and I don't understand why

The **script functions**

```
function renderQuestion(question){

    // load correct and incorrect areas 
    question.$correctArea.appendTo($questionMap);
    question.$incorrectArea.appendTo($questionMap);

    // set question background image
    $questionImage.attr({
        src: question.backgroundImage
    }); 
}

function onCorrect(){
    score++;
    loadNextQuestion();
}

function onIncorrect(){
    $questionImage.attr({
        src: "../img/items/fail.png"
    });
}

function loadNextQuestion(){
    renderQuestion(questions[questionIndex]);
    questionIndex++;
}

// load first question
loadNextQuestion();

// clicks
$('.correct-area').click(function(){
    onCorrect();
});
$('.incorrect-area').click(function(){
    onIncorrect();
});
```

The game is online at:
http://i333180.iris.fhict.nl/demo/pages/index.php

As you can notice, at the questions, it loads the first one right with the right areas.
After clicking the right answer, the next question is loaded but the new areas are not replaced.
Do someone see it?

**EDIT**
Changed the function renderQuestion:

```
    function renderQuestion(question){

    // load correct and incorrect areas 
    $questionMap.html(question.$incorrectArea);
    $questionMap.html(question.$correctArea);

    // set question background image
    $questionImage.attr({
        src: question.backgroundImage
    }); 

    // clicks
    $('.correct-area').on('click', onCorrect);
    $('.incorrect-area').on('click', onIncorrect);
}
```

The clicks are working the right way and the correct area is added. But by using .html it only adds the last area and I neem them both

Comment: Do you think you could come up with a better title for your question?

Comment: The title is no good? Els Ill replace that one! Sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty the question map before you start appending to it.

```
function renderQuestion(question){
    // Clear out old questions
    $questionMap.empty();
    // load correct and incorrect areas 
    question.$correctArea.appendTo($questionMap);
    question.$incorrectArea.appendTo($questionMap);

    // set question background image
    $questionImage.attr({
        src: question.backgroundImage
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function renderQuestion(question){

    // load correct and incorrect areas 

    $questionMap.html(question.$correctArea)
    $questionMap.append(question.$incorrectArea)

    // set question background image
    $questionImage.attr({
        src: question.backgroundImage
    }); 
}
```

Using the `html()` method replaces the content instead of just appending the new stuff to the bottom. I'm not sure if your `$questionMap` is a jQuery object, if not, wrap it as you would anything else (`$($questionMap)`) and it should work.

Comment: This seems to work but only on one area and I neem them both

Comment: Calling `.html()` twice in a row on the same DIV will just overwrite that the first one did.

Comment: Do you know how I add/replace both areas?